# How to maximize marquee animation base on the text length

Tags: html, css, css-animations

```css
@keyframes slide {
  from {
    left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    left: -100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  from {
    left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    left: -100%;
  }
}

#marquee {
  color: var(--gray-dark);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#announcement_text {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1000%;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center breaking-news bg-white">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-grow-1 flex-fill justify-content-center bg-danger py-2 text-white news">
    <span class="d-flex align-items-center">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="far fa-newspaper"> 
                  </i>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div id="marquee">
    <div style="color:black; paddingleft:5px;" id="announcement_text">
      LONG MESSAGE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: sorry for my bad English
I am trying to scroll long messages especially an article with this code but the marquee animation cuts the text and repeats from the start. A help would be greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: I think marquee HTML tag is more suitable for this job. You can read more here https://www.w3schools.in/html-tutorial/marquee-tag/

Comment: i tried it and it worked! thank you